# question about a probability problem

Tags: probability

i am having trouble figuring out the answer to a tricky question. i hope someone here can tell me if i'm at least on the right track here.

probabilities that a part works for a year. the device has two parts.

$P(c_1) = 0.93$

$P(c_2) = 0.87$

probabilities that each part of the device will fail within a year.

$P(c_1^{F}) = 0.07$

$P(c_2^{F}) = 0.13$

probability that part 2 fails given that part 1 fails:

$P(c_2^{F} | c_1^{F}) = p$

i used a bit of algebra with the conditional probability formula to find the probability that both parts 1 and 2 will fail:

$P(c_2^{F} \cap c_1^{F}) = 0.07p$

i need to know the probability that both parts will work for a year. i believe this is the complement of the above result.

am i right?

thank you for any insight.

Comment: The complement to "both fail", by De Morgan, is "at least one works", or $P(c_1 \cup c_2)$. You need Inclusion-Exclusion to find $P(c_2^F \cup c_1^F)$, then take the complement.

Comment: If you are trying to find the probability that both parts work for a year, that is a simple multiplication of $p(c_1)$ and $p(c_2)$. So I am not clear why you are doing these steps. Can you clarify?

Comment: You just need to use the fact that $P(c_2 \cup c_1) = 1 - P(c_2^{F} \cap c_1^{F})$.

Comment: @MathLover i was thinking this too at first, but it seems like i overthought it...

Comment: OK, if you take probability for each part failing while other part works, probability for both parts failing, add them and subtract from $1$, it is same as simple multiplication of $p(c_1)$ and $p(c_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(\overline{C_1}\cap \overline{C_2})=P\overline{(C_1\cup C_2)}=1-[P(C_1)+P(C_2)-P(C_1\cap C_2)]$$

Thus

$$P(C_1\cap C_2)=0.80+0.07p$$